# Merging two Data sets based on k-1 common columns values

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to merge two data frames in a such a manner that if two data set's value in k-1 columns are same, combine the common k-1 columns with other 2 non-common columns, into one data-set?

Thanks!

```
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c('+'), X2 = c('+'), X3 = c('O'))
df1

df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c('+'), X2 = c('+'), X3 = c('X'))
df2
```

Expected

```
df12 <- data.frame(X1 = c('+'), X2 = c('+'), X3 = c('O'),X4 = c('X')) 
df12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df12 <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("X1", "X2"))
names(df12)[3:4] <- paste0("X", 3:4)
```

Please see the help manual of `merge` for more info. Type "?merge" in R console.

Comment: Although, it's not general but I got the idea how to manipulate as per my requirement. Thanks!

Comment: `df12 <- merge(df1, df2, by=names(df)[-(k-1)])`

Comment: Great! Cheers. @Prerit